# Getting dictionary key from Image sender

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, dictionary

So in WPF C# I have a Dictionary(string, Image) called dict. I also have a Brick class which has a name and other values. The string key in the dictionary matches to its respective Brick via the name variable and I also have a List(Brick) called bricks

I am adding the dict[bricks[this_brick].Name] as a child to the canvas and I also add a LeftMouseButtonUp property to the image. When I click on the image I want to find out the key of the image that I just clicked so that I can loop through my bricks and compare the name of the brick against the key of the brick clicked in order to get the data for that brick.

However, the sender on MouseLeftButtonUp is of Image type and I don't know how to gain the key from it. Are there and BIF in the sender which will give me the key? I looked through the list of attributes of sender whilst debugging and couldn't see the key anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get access to the key would be to set it as the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, as in:

```
string key = bricks[this_brick].Name;
Image image = dict[key];
image.Tag = key;
```

That way you can easily retrieve it from the sender:

```
private void MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    var image = (Image)sender;
    string key = image.Tag as string; 

    // ...
}
```